# squid reply_body_max_size not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid

I have been tasked to limit bandwidth consumption. I have setup squid as a transparent proxy and am blocking various content types i.e video, x-flv... The content type acl's seems to work fine. I have also setup the reply_body_max_size to 10 MB but large file downloads are still happening. This one just last night got through.

```
1331243510.997 621794 192.168.0.100 TCP_MISS/200 37603388 GET http://cache.pack.google.com/edgedl/chrome/mac/GoogleChrome-17.0.963.78.dmg - DIRECT/173.194.12.207 application/x-apple-diskimage
```

here is my directive: (squid was restarted after the change)

```
reply_body_max_size 10 MB
```

From reading the squid documentation http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_body_max_size/ looks like there might be some issue with other downstream squid proxy server. I know that the ISP they use (Tachyon Systems) have a squid proxy server built-in their modem.

Could this be why the reply_body_max_size doesn't work in my enviroment?

Comment: Where is your proxy in relation to the client, the modem and the internet?  I suspect the modem is actually *upstream* and would not be affected by the issue mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: It is upstream. I have implemented what proy suggested below but haven't yet tested. More to come...

Answer (score 1):

As the [Squid documentation](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_body_max_size/) says, the reply_body_max_size configuration directive causes Squid to cease transmission when the HTTP reply body exceeds the size specified.  This is checked by Squid in two ways: using the HTTP Content-Length: header, if present - in this case, the reply will not be allowed and a TCP_DENIED_REPLY will be written to the log.  Or, if a HTTP Content-Length: header is not present, then the reply will be allowed, but the connection will be closed when reply_body_max_size is reached.

In the second scenario, there could have a potentially important knock-on effect for any cache downstream from you.  If the HTTP transmission was started without a HTTP Content-length: header, and your copy of Squid subsequently dropped the connection when the reply size limit was reached, the downstream cache won't know that the connection was dropped before the full reply body was sent.  This could result in an incomplete copy of the object being stored in the downstream cache.  However, based on your description, I don't think that's the case here, as you are talking about an upstream proxy operated by your ISP.

On that note, there's no way that I can see where an upstream proxy could possibly affect your ability to impose a limit on the reply body size.

One note on the syntax in your configuration.  You have specified:

```
reply_body_max_size 10 MB
```

When I think this should actually be:

```
reply_body_max_size 10 MB all
```

Note the ACL name "all" at the end.  The Squid documentation places the list of ACLs in square brackets, which tends to indicate this parameter is optional, and in my testing, I've certainly found that to be the case.  However, there's a variation of this syntax in some places on the net (and in this thread above), where sometimes the word "allow" or "deny" is also placed in the configuration line.  According to the Squid documentation, and my testing, this is incorrect.  The syntax above has tested correctly for me.

Nb. testing conducted with Squid 3.1.23 and Squid 3.5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should try applying that to you source acl. For eg: something like this

`acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16`
`reply_body_max_size 52428800 deny localnet`
 
`http_access allow localnet`